# What is the name of this variegated plant?

Tags: identification, plant-care, indoors

I've had it for a month, but lost the tag with info on it. if anyone has the name and/or helpful info, I'd really appreciate it. I don't want to kill it! all I know is it's two toned, it's been indoors since I bought too. I water it like one or twice a week and I don't know how much sun it needs.

[image: picture of variegated plant in question]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a variegated [vinca or periwinkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinca). There are a couple of species that differ in the size of the leaves; I will let you read up on that. Often used in shady places under trees, has a small bluish flowers and the giveaway in your photo is the long trailing stems with opposite leaves.